# For some reason, datasets change size

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I am making aut-ml program for a school competition.

I ran into a problem in which when loading datasets, for some reason, their size changes. Because of this, I cannot use them in machine learning algorithms.

Real size of 1.csv is (515, 12),
Real size of 2.csv is (31, 12).

```
data = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
X = pd.DataFrame(data)
data_predict = pd.read_csv('2.csv')
X_predict = pd.DataFrame(data_predict)
X_s = X.shape                     # output (515, 986)
X_predict_s = X_predict.shape     # output (31, 136)
```

I've tried a lot, including this:

```
pd.concat([X[i] for i in X.columns]).dropna()
pd.concat([X_predict[i] for i in X_predict.columns]).dropna()

X.dropna(inplace=True)
indices_to_keep = X.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf])
X_predict.dropna(inplace=True)
indices_to_keep = X_predict.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf])
```

I also tried writing a dataset to an Excel file (using `pd.read_excel`)

[image: 1st file]
[image: 2nd file]
[3rd file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbHx1.png)

Comment: can you show us some rows of the cvs files? By the way ```X = pd.read_csv('1.csv')``` would already create a DataFrame from the csv file.

Comment: Added 2 screenshots. Ignore the 13th column in the first file

Comment: can you open the files in a text editor (not in excel)? I suspect that there are many commas added in every row when you save the file in excel.

Comment: No, it is unlikely that the excel is to blame. I also tried using LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: I replaced 1.csv and 2.csv with the classic Titanic passenger dataset. The size of datasets has become normal. Perhaps the problem is specifically in this dataset, although I recreated it many times, even in different versions of Excel

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `scikit-learn` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).